# Implications of changing RAND() value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, random

I have a members table which contains one row for each members of my site. New members are constantly being added.

For various reasons I want to introduce a field named "random" in my table which will be updated intermittently and will affect the ordering of results when people browse other peoples profiles on my site.

So basically, my plan is to have a cron job that runs a couple of times throughout the day and does an update on the random column as follows;

```
SET @random = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members);
UPDATE members SET random = FLOOR(RAND()*(@random-1)+1);
```

My questions are;

Can I still add an index to this column to speed up queries on the table? i.e. will it be rebuilt each time the query executes?

Is there any way to avoid duplicate random values?

Comment: Why not just create a new table with reference to members table?

Comment: Sorry Jack, not sure what you mean. What would the benefits be of creating a new table?

Comment: Why add a column called random that has absolutely nothing to do with members at all?

Comment: To randomly display profiles. Using a rand() ordering function will cause other issues